# Why NSString says it is "Invalid", objC, IPhone?

Tags: iphone, nsstring, nsdictionary, objective-c

I have a ViewController, 
i declare 
NSString *xTitle at the top in testViewController.m file

when i set the xTitle=@"anytext" in viewload event;
and i tap a button, it shows the UIActionsheet.

i try to read xTitle in UIActionSheet's clickedButtonAtIndex.
i see the xTitle's value "anytext", its ok.

but when i set the xTitle from NSDictionary, it says Invalid.

viewload event;

```
NSDictionary *results = [jsonString JSONValue];
xTitle  = [results valueForKey:@"ContentURL"];
```

`NSLog(@"%@", xTitle);`--> it writes the value
but i cant read xTitle in uiactionsheet events. it says invalid.

why does it say "Invalid"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want the string to outlive the function, you probably need to do:

```
xTitle = [[results valueForKey:@"ContentURL"] retain];
```

And of course `release` it at some subsequent point when you're finished with it.

This doesn't affect you when using the NSString literal `@"anytext"` because constant strings are basically static -- that is, they normally stick around for the whole lifetime of your code. You *can* (and maybe in some pedantic sense should) `retain` and `release` these too, but it doesn't actually do anything to them.

(I'm a little bit curious about the scoping of this -- if `xTitle` is declared at the top of the `.m` file, how do you get at it in your action sheet -- but I don't think that's germane to this problem.)

Comment: what is the difference between if i give the value xTitle=@"anytext",
or xTitle  = [results valueForKey:@"ContentURL"]?
if i set xtitle=@"anytext", it works in every event.
yes retain works. but i dont understand why?

Comment: cas actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex is in the same .m file.

Comment: @tester see somewhat expanded explanation above

Answer (score 0):

Try doing

```
NSLog (@"%@", results);
```

Direcly after you create it to see exactly what is in the dictionary. Edit to show us what is in the dictionary.

Comment: {
    CommentCount = 15;
    ContentDeck = "Lorem Ipsum.";
    ContentURL = "/content/18888/lorem";
    ContentID = 18888;
    ThumbnailURL = "http://media1.dummy.net///C/I//42/masada38_4ZK6T.jpg";
    VideoURL = "";
}

Comment: i read the value just after xTitle  = [results valueForKey:@"ContentURL"];
NSLog(@"%@", xTitle);
but it doesnt show the value in different event???